# Issues with Javascript and IE9

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-9

I have this javascript code to show a message on launching a website:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title:'Welcome to Site',
        msg:'Welcome to this website!.',
        buttons:Ext.MessageBox.OK,
        icon:Ext.MessageBox.INFO
    });
});
```

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but displays badly in Internet Explorer 9. Any ideas on how to fix the the problem?

Comment: Doesn't show text, only creates a window with yes, no cancel in.....

Comment: if it not run in IE then it gives an error ? if give and error what kind of error?

Comment: It runs in IE, just the message box doesn't display correctly.

Comment: What version of Extjs are you using?

Comment: Unsure, how would I find out?

Comment: Maybe a CSS issue? Hard to tell with only this info. Please post a jsfiddle.net link reproducing the issue.

Comment: What @bfavaretto said, this is probably a CSS issue.

Comment: To figure out which version of Extjs, you could check the Ext.versions.core.major and Ext.versions.core.minor variables.

Comment: This is probably **not** a CSS issue. Ext.js up to V3.3 has **issues** with determining when onReady has occurred. It's time to upgrade to 3.4 or cross fingers for 4.x conversion. Random firing of onReady events is a known issue and has been from IE 8, forward.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet of code seems to produce the same results in Chrome and IE9. Check below

[image: Test results]

Could you upload a pic of what you are observing??

Comment: Don't have enough rep to comment above, so posting this as an Answer! Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by the need for a version upgrade of Ext.js.

Versions previous to 3.4 have issues either with the Browser Version sniffing or a timing error that prevents `Ext.onReady` from properly determining when that event has occurred.

One specific error that Internet Explorer 9 throws is null or undefined objects being passed:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'addClass': object is null or undefined

From code snippets like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        var tabs = new Ext.ux.Tabs('tabs',
            activeTab: 'tab-description'
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

It's a very simple tab panel, works in everything but IE 9 and fails because it's complaining that `'tabs'` cannot be passed to the following code in the Ext code:

```
constructor : function(element, config) {
    Ext.apply(this, config);
    Ext.ux.Tabs.superclass.constructor.call(this);

    this.addEvents(
        'beforetabchange',
        'tabchange'
    );

    this.el = Ext.get(element);
    this.init();
},

init : function() {
    var me = this;

    this.el.addClass('ux-tabs-container');
```

So `this.el = Ext.get(element);` fails to find the element identified as `tabs` and causes `this.el.addClass('ux-tabs-container');` to die.

If anyone has a crutch for getting older versions to overcome this issue on a temporary basis, please feel free to comment.